# Sending serialized objects through the internet

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, communication

I am developing a program for our organization. My program (C# desktop program on Windows 7) consists of 2 sub programs: a "server" program and a "client" program.

The "server" program will be installed in the head office and receives info from branches about who and in what subject each employee was trained in. It has a PostgreSQL database back end.

The "client" program will be installed in branches of the organization (currently 9 branches), it will have a file based database (undecided yet) and is responsible for gathering info about who got training in that particular branch and in which subject.

So, every day (give or take) every branch will send training statistics to the main office's server program (? serialized objects), the main office will receive the objects and store them in the database and will reply with some info, things like "ok confirmed" or "yes, you can do that" or "no, refused". At the end of the month the head office computer will process the data and print some statistics. So real time communication between branches and server is absolutely NOT necessary.

**The question**: given that those computers are over the internet and can't communicate with each other directly (we have dynamic IP addressing in our country), how can I get those serialized objects from clients to the server and vice versa ?

My thinking is that I can use email (send files as attachments) or maybe on any cloud file sharing program (Dropbox or OneDrive... etc). But I am not an expert programmer and I would like to know how these things are done.

p.s.: cloud database is not an option. for performance reasons + I don't want our info in someone else's hands. A way of communication is OK because stuff will be signed and encrypted in transit.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to communicate directly? You only care about request-response communication, which is pretty easy. Just setup an encrypted WCF endpoint, ideally with a very restrictive firewall (IP filtering?), and you're done.

Comment: *giving that those computers are over the internet and obviously can't communicate with each others directly* Computers on the internet communicate directly all the time, if yours can't you need to tell us why, because then there will have to be an internet proxy or buffering server of some sort between them.

Comment: we have dynamic IP in our country. and of course NAT in our router.

Answer (score 0):

It seems HTTP server with REST API will suit you quite good. You will need to forward a TCP port from your server to outer Internet (contact your internet provider on this matter if not sure).

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution to this problem turned out to be easy . dynamic DNS + port forwarding .